# Как я могу вызывать функцию, которая изменяет положение элемента с помощью "timer->tick = EventHandler(...)"?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, события, c++-cli, таймер

Я хочу изменять местоположение элемента формы через одинаковый промежуток времени. Как мне вызвать функцию через EventHandler. Или есть другой способ?

`//вызываемая функция`

```cpp
System::Void PharmacyDB::Game::_update(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e)
{
    pictureBoxCube->Location = Point(pictureBoxCube->Location.X + dirX * _sizeOfSides, pictureBoxCube->Location.Y + dirY * _sizeOfSides);
    return System::Void();
}
```

`//Функция, из которой вызываю (отрабатывает при каждой загрузке формы`

```cpp
System::Void PharmacyDB::Game::Game_Shown(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e)
{
    this->timer->Tick += gcnew EventHandler(_update);
    return System::Void();
}
```

_update горит красным, ошибка:

недопустимый инициализатор делегата -- функция не соответствует типу делегата &: недопустимая операция с выражением привязанной функции-члена.
System::EventHandler: недопустимый аргумент для конструктора делегата; целевой объект делегата должен быть указателем на функцию-член

Если я делаю функцию статической, ошибка пропадает, но исчезает возможность изменять свойства элемента формы.
Через событие таймера Tick это сделать тоже не получилось (не понял как)

Так

```cpp
this->timer->Tick += gcnew EventHandler(this, _update);
```

тоже ошибку выдает:

Ошибка  C3867   "PharmacyDB::Game::_update": нестандартный синтаксис; используйте "&", чтобы создать указатель на член

Comment: `gcnew EventHandler(this, _update)`

Comment: Переведите вопрос на русский язык. В противном случае он будет закрыт.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov 
this->timer->Tick += gcnew EventHandler(this, &PharmacyDB::Game::_update);
Заработало, спасибо!

Comment: @dIm0n - C++ и C++/CLI - разные языки. Зря вы поставили метку языка, не имеющего отношения к вопросу.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov почему зря? У вопроса нет ответов до сих пор, а у [tag:c++-cli] - 11 отслеживающих, в то время как у [tag:c++] - 959

Comment: @dIm0n - А у C# ещё больше отслеживающих. И у некоторых других языков. Но это _другие_ языки. А вопрос именно по синтаксису C++/CLI.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov [Использовать совместно с меткой используемого языка: c или c++](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/visual-c%2b%2b/info)

Comment: По хорошему, метку "visual-c++" тоже следует удалить. А также "события" и "timer". Но с метками вечно путаница. / Суть вопроса: синтаксис определения делегатов (функторов).